# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this as a fun little practice with my beginner coding knowledge in python 3.5.

```
def potato_quant(number):
    if number >= 5 and number < 100:
        print("You've got more than 5 potatoes. Making a big meal eh?")
    elif number >= 100 and number < 10000:
        print("You've got more than 100 potatoes! What do you need all those potatoes for?")
    elif number >= 10000 and number < 40000:
        print("You've got more than 10000! Nobody needs that many potatoes!")
    elif number >= 40000:
        print("You've got more than 40000 potatoes. wut.")
    elif number == 0:
        print("No potatoes eh?")
    elif number < 5:
        print("You've got less than five potatoes. A few potatoes go a long way.")
    else:
        return 0
 def potato_type(variety):
     if variety == "Red":
        print("You have chosen Red potatoes.")
     elif variety == "Sweet":
        print("You have chosen the tasty sweet potato.")
     elif variety == "Russet":
          print("You've got the tasty average joe potatoe!")
     else:
          print("Nice potato!")

print(potato_quant(15000) + potato_type("Sweet"))
```

The goal of the code was to input two values and get two strings based on my choice. However, when I run the code I get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

I'm very much a beginner, so no matter how much I look over this I can't see what's wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated, mostly for future use.

Comment: You return None in most cases from your function (as you don't specify a value to return when you print).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `print` with `return` and you're good to go:

```
def potato_quant(number):
    if number >= 5 and number < 100:
        return("You've got more than 5 potatoes. Making a big meal eh?")
    elif number >= 100 and number < 10000:
        return("You've got more than 100 potatoes! What do you need all those potatoes for?")
    elif number >= 10000 and number < 40000:
        return("You've got more than 10000! Nobody needs that many potatoes!")
    elif number >= 40000:
        return("You've got more than 40000 potatoes. wut.")
    elif number == 0:
        return("No potatoes eh?")
    elif number < 5:
        return("You've got less than five potatoes. A few potatoes go a long way.")
    else:
        return '0'

def potato_type(variety):
    if variety == "Red":
        return("You have chosen Red potatoes.")
    elif variety == "Sweet":
        return("You have chosen the tasty sweet potato.")
    elif variety == "Russet":
        return("You've got the tasty average joe potatoe!")
    else:
        return("Nice potato!")

print(potato_quant(15000) + potato_type("Sweet"))
```

In the line `print(potato_quant(15000) + potato_type("Sweet"))`, you're calling the functions `potato_quant` & `potato_type` which have to return a value to be printed.

Since your functions had `print` instead of `return`, they return `None` and the operand `+` is undefined on `None`. Hence the error message.

And if `potato_quant` return `0`, it'll raise `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`. So I replaced `return 0` with `replace '0'` to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Since `potato_quant` and `potato_type` already do the printing, you don't need to call them inside of a `print` call.

The error you're getting is because the functions don't have a `return` statement other than in the `else`, so be default it returns `None`

All you really need to do is change the last line:

```
print(potato_quant(15000) + potato_type("Sweet"))
```

to

```
potato_quant(1500)
potato_type("Sweet")
```